# Find vowel number in words

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int counter = 0;
    List<string> namesList = new List<string>();
    List<char> vowels = new List<char>() { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the word");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        namesList.Add(userInput);
        foreach (char c in userInput)
        {
            if (vowels.Contains(c))
            {
                counter++;                        
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("In the word {0} is {1} vowels", namesList[i], counter);

    }
}
```

I'm trying to find vowels in the words which user will input in the console, however with counter I can manage to count the total number of vowels in 5 words, but not separately,can someone advise how can I do that? In the above code counter is counting like this 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... and if the second word contains 2 vowels it shows the number 5.

Comment: You need to reset `counter = 0;` each time through the outer loop.

Comment: That worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Simplify* your code, *extract method*, let `counter` belongs to `CountVowels` only:

```
 //TODO: HashSet<char> can well appear a better collection
 private static List<char> s_Vowels = new List<char>() {
   'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};

 private static int CountVowels(string value) {
   // Or one line Linq: 
   // return value.Count(c => s_Vowels.Contains(c));
   int count = 0;

   foreach (char c in value) 
     if (s_Vowels.Contains(c))
       count += 1;

   return count;
 }
```

Then use it:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  List<string> namesList = new List<string>();

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)  {
    namesList.Add(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine($"In the word {namesList[i]} is {CountVowels(namesList[i])} vowels");
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use regular expression to match vowels in a sentence.
**Regex.Matches()** function will return an array with all occurrence of vowel.
We can then use count property to find the count of vowels.

**Regular expression to match vowels in a string:*[aeiouAEIOU]+***

> Below is the working code snippet:

```
 public static void Main()
   {
       string pattern = @"[aeiouAEIOU]+";
       Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
       string sentence = "Who writes these notes?";
       Console.WriteLine(rgx.Matches(sentence).Count);
   }
```